# Calling class method in callback/event - jQuery

Tags: jquery, callback

I have defined a Javascript 'popup window' class using code similar to below:

```
function Popup(strPopContID)
{
    this.strPopupContaineriD=strPopContID;

    /* code creates popup with ID equal to value of strPopContID with 'close button' in
       the top bar of popup with class 'CloseButton'*/

    classThisPopup=this;
    $('#'+this.strPopupContaineriD+' .CloseButton').click(function(){
       classThisPopup.ClosePopup();
    })


    this.ClosePopup=function(){
       $('#'+this.strPopupContaineriD).remove();
     }
}
```

Now if I create two instances of my class:

```
Popup1 = new Popup('FirstContainer');
Popup2 = new Popup('SecondContainer');
```

I can close them fine using Popup1.ClosePopup() and Popup2.ClosePopup() but clicking on the close buttons will only close one box. I seem to understand that calling ClosePopup as 'click' option from JQuery messes up the variable scope which is why my 'ClosePopup' function only reacts to the latest popup created but is there any way I can get around that without a necessity to pass any arguments to 'ClosePopup'?

Comment: in the constructor  Popup1 = new Popup(); shouldn't you use some parameter like Popup1 = new Popup("mypopup1");

Comment: Yes, it was just something I missed when posting the question, container names are created fine in my code. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `var` for the `classThisPopup` variable, so it's declared on the global object (window).

Once you change  `classThisPopup=this;` to `var classThisPopup=this;` it should work.

Comment: Oh my God - how did I missed that?! Thank you very much.